# What is the latest url of grails repo? (repo.grails.org/grails/repo vs repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)

Tags: grails

We were trying use https://grails.org/plugin/jms for jms integration. But we were not able to resolve it.

Upon looking around, I was able to verify that it exists on this repo:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo

But the grailsCentral() repo points to: https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins

We are using grails 2.4.4

Is the /grails/repo/ the new repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [GitHub search](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=grailsCentral) against the latest source reveals:

```
DEFAULT_REPO = new RepositoryConfiguration("grailsCentral", new URI("https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"), true)
```

So, our latest `grailsCentral` URI is `https://repo.grails.org/grails/core`

Digging deeper:

```
git log --pickaxe-regex -S"grailsCentral.*repo\.grails.org/grails/core"

git tag --contains 5fd5a7ae23ce7ea14ebabd09ffb081e6a32d356f
```

This change was introduced in Grails 3.0.0.

Comment: For grails 2.x.x, do we use the updated grails repo? Or do we stick with the old repo?

Comment: The semantics of grailsCentral changed from a "plugin" to a "core" repo. If you just need to resolve grails plugins, [use plugin.](https://repo.grails.org/grails/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/simple/General/plugins)  If you need other depenedencies as well, [use grails and core](https://repo.grails.org/grails/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/simple/General/core)

Comment: I meant to say "plugin and core", sorry. The empirical way to determine what you need is to delete your .grails dir and try sparsest combinations of repo entries until you get all deps resolved.